# How to increase my SSD performance?

Tags: performance, system-settings

I use Transcend 120-GB SSD drive with 1-TB HDD drive.
My machine is DELL Inspiron-5567 (laptop).
Ram 12-GB with 2-GB Swap Memory from the SSD drive.

Now I'm asking sir, can I use Trim Technology?
And is there any disadvantage the TRIM Technology?

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if your ssd is trim active with this command

```
`sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM`
```

If trim is available on your ssd you will see an output similar to this.

`Data Set Management TRIM supported`

If it does you can benefit from setting up trim. 
In fact this [whole article](https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/ssd.html#ID8.2) should work for you.

Just replace xed in the commands with gedit or whatever text editor you are using.